# Animating frame by frame with a setInterval replacement in JQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, setinterval

So I'm making a basic function in JQuery to trigger an animation when hovered over. Instead of using a gif, I'm trying to "switch" between png images in an array since a gif won't give me the quality I'm looking for, and svg animations seem to be aimed for posable figures.

But, the animation so far is extremely slow. Setinterval is what seems to be recommended to get the images switching, but I was wondering if there's a better alternative?

Thanks!

```js
var frames = ["images/ruby/ruby0002.png", "images/ruby/ruby0004.png", "images/ruby/ruby0006.png", "images/ruby/ruby0007.png" , "images/ruby/ruby0008.png", , "images/ruby/ruby0009.png", "images/ruby/ruby0010.png"];
var index = 0;
$( "#Image" ).hover(function(imgAnimate) {
function imgAnimate()
{
  $('#Image').animate('fast', function()
  {
    $(this).attr('src', images[index]);
    $(this).animate('fast', function()
    {
      if (index === frames.length -1)
      {
        index = 0;
      }
      else
      {
        index++;
      }
    });
  });
}

  $(document).ready(function()
    {
      setInterval(imgAnimate, 1000); //setTimeout has a similar outcome in this case, after testing it
    });

    });
```

Comment: Are you open to using and animating a vector instead? Much better clarity than PNG, less overhead, and you can use tools designed for the task, like Greensock.

Answer (score 0):

If you really can't use GIF you can always preload your images.

Add **html**:

```
<img id='my_image' src='http://www.radbs.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/Mystery-Person-Silhouette.jpg' width='300'>
```

*Preload* all **images**:

```
my_images = ['https://assets2.hrc.org/files/images/resources/ComintOut-AsianPacificAmerican.png', 'https://qph.fs.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-a798e466698fa737c8853fe2217fc8ec-c','https://www.essence.com/sites/default/files/images/embed/black_woman_serious.jpg','https://i.pinimg.com/originals/74/5a/5f/745a5ff00611171a5f769c1ca10c4b4e.jpg','http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2011/09/11/article-0-0DD59D6900000578-459_634x657.jpg']

function preload(my_images) {
    $(my_images).each(function(){
        $('<img/>')[0].src = this;
    });
}

preload(my_images);
```

**Loop** through all preloaded images on **hover**:

```
cnt=0;
function loop_images() {
$('#my_image').attr('src', my_images[cnt])
setTimeout(function() {loop_images()},1500)
cnt++;
}

$('#my_image').on('mouseenter', function() {
loop_images();
})
```

**Result**:

[image]

**But** reducing your interval time is unlikely to allow smooth animations to happen. This is why GIFs and WEBGL exist.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/CyberneticSean/4xn3f87x/24/#&togetherjs=JugFzTdJd4)